Failed to release a CodePush update
When I want to release codePush on updates to my project, I always get the problem when releasing the code, I have tried repeatedly by making sure the configuration is correct but the problem is still reduced again, is it possible that there is an incompatibility with the project version that I have ? the problem is below
the problem:
node node_modules/.bin/react-native bundle --assets-dest /tmp/code-push2024422-21122-r1x5ft.f36ut/CodePush --bundle-output /tmp/code-push2024422-21122-r1x5ft.f36ut/CodePush/index.android.bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --platform android
Error: Failed to release a CodePush update.
I'm trying to release the codePush update and hope this problem is resolved.

Please check this question from 2018. If that has inadequate information, please edit the question to delimit error output with triple-back-ticks so that others can tell where the line-breaks are. It's possible that there's a line of error output missing.
